# preg_match how should I use

Tags: php

I have a string to check and if it is only numbers and digits perform another action else exit;

```
$data = 123412347JB91742F;

 if(preg_match('/[A-Z1-9]/', $data )) {
  echo $data;

} 
else { 
  exit; 
}
```

this works fine but if I add anything to `$data` like `$` or any other thing it still prints the value. What is wrong with this code?

### Edit:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\-/', '', '1234-1234-JB91-8742F');

if(preg_match('/^[A-Z1-9]+$/', $data )) {
    echo $data;
} else {
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, did you mean to block the usage of the number 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your regex will match every string containing a digit or "normal" character.
2. $data needs to be in quotes.

Your code should look like this:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z1-9]+$/', $data)
```

Do you want to match zeros as well as lower case characters? Then your regex should look like this:

```
preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i', $data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression just checks if there is at least one character of that set. Try this regular expression instead:

```
/^[A-Z1-9]+$/
```

The anchors `^` and `$` mark the start and end of the string.